# Putting React templates in properties of one global variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible to store some React templates in properties of one global variable?
I mean that I want to create two child templates:

```
app.templates.CommonProducts = React.createClass(/* any render, etc */);
```

and

```
app.templates.DiscountProducts = React.createClass(/* any render, etc */);
```

How can I get these templates in "parent" template? What tag names (CommonProducts, DiscountProducts) should look like?

```
app.templates.Products = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <CommonProducts></CommonProducts>
                <DiscountProducts></DiscountProducts>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called [`Namespaced Components`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#namespaced-components),

```
app.templates.Products = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <app.templates.DiscountProducts></app.templates.DiscountProducts>
        <app.templates.CommonProducts></app.templates.CommonProducts>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/29309/)